# Can't access a directory I am a group member of

Tags: permissions

I have a directory ‘/mnt/media/’ that has the permission drwxrwxr-x-- and user:group luthing:users so all the users can access it (shared disk).

Permissions are :

```
ls -lisa /mnt/media
total 32
7077889 4 drwxrwxr-x 8 luthing users 4096 mai    4 14:44 .
 262162 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root  4096 mai   22 16:07 ..
7077900 4 drwxrwxr-x 2 luthing users 4096 mai    4 16:58 folder1
7077890 4 drwxrwxr-x 2 luthing users 4096 mai    4 17:24 folder2
```

I created a new user and added to the group :

```
    #sudo -u newuser id
    uid=1002(newuser) gid=1002(newuser) groupes=1002(newuser),100(users) 
    #egrep /etc/groups newuser
    users:x:100:user1,user2,newuser
    newuser:x:1002:
```

However, when I try to touch :

```
# sudo -u newuser touch /mnt/media/folder1/test
touch: cannot touch '/mnt/media/folder1/test': Permission denied
```

Any idea ? I can't figure it out

Comment: It's `mount`ed Read Only? See https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld to investigate.

Comment: Hey! Here is my fstab file :

`192.168.1.1:/media    /mnt/media      nfs     defaults,user,rw        0       0`

And the output of the mount command :

`192.168.1.1:/media on /mnt/media type nfs4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=0.0.0.0,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.1,user)`